# The image background of my LinearLyout, containing a webview, doesn't appear

Tags: java, android, webview

I have a fragment containing a LinearLayout containing a webview, when a change the html string in my webview, sometimes the background of my LinearLayout doesn't appear.
My fragment:

`

```
 <ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:scrollbarStyle="outsideOverlay"
        tools:context=".NewsFragment" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/linearLayout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="10dp"
            android:background="@drawable/bg_item_single"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:padding="@dimen/list_margin" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/text"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_margin="16dp"
                android:textColor="#000"
                android:textSize="20sp" />

            <WebView
                android:id="@+id/webview"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:background="@drawable/transparent" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

`

If I have a linearLayout in a other linearLayout is just to have a space on the bottom of my scrollView, isn't the problem.

My code:
`

```
private void populate() {

        textView.setText(grant.getName());
        // Configure w`enter code here`ebview
        webview.getSettings().setCacheMode(WebSettings.LOAD_NO_CACHE);
        webview.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(false);
        webview.setBackgroundColor(Color.argb(1, 0, 0, 0));
        webview.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {

            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                return (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE);

            }
        });

        webview.loadDataWithBaseURL("file:///android_asset/", createFullHtmlPage("styles.css", grant.getGrantDescription(), 0), "text/html", "UTF-8", null);

    }
```

`

I don't see were is the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed my problem. I used a shape as background of my LinearLayout, but if the webview is too big, for unknown reason, the shape don't work and don't appear. Therefore now I use a color background and 2 imageview for creat a bottom corner and top corner.

```
 <ScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:scrollbarStyle="outsideOverlay"
    tools:context=".NewsFragment" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:paddingBottom="50dp" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="10dp"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@drawable/bg_item_top" />

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@color/bg_item_default"
                android:orientation="vertical" >

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/text"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_margin="16dp"
                    android:textColor="#000"
                    android:textSize="20sp" />

                <WebView
                    android:id="@+id/webview"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_margin="@dimen/list_margin" />
            </LinearLayout>

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@drawable/bg_item_bottom" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try setting `android:layout_height="wrap_content"`, and remove the transparent background of this view.

```
<WebView
    android:id="@+id/webview"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/transparent" />
```

Comment: I tried it but it didn't fix my problem, but you're right `android:background="@drawable/transparent"` is useless.`webview.setBackgroundColor(Color.argb(1, 0, 0, 0));` make the transparent background.

Answer (score 0):

How I undestud problem is in this line

```
webview.setBackgroundColor(Color.argb(1, 0, 0, 0));
```

try this

```
webview.setBackgroundResource(color.blue);
```

Comment: I don't want a blue background for my webview but a transparent background. The background who doesn't appear is the background of my linearLayout containing my webview.

Comment: make color transparent: `webview.setBackgroundResource(new Color(100,200,50,100));` -> here(100,200,50) - is your color, and last 100 - transparent coeficient (0 - 255). Try to change it, and i think you can solve your problem